# MSVC++ compile only / disable linker

Tags: java, c++, assembly, java-native-interface

I need to compile some C++ code that will be called from Java with JNI, and these C++ functions have to call an Assembly function (assembled with NASM), so the C++ functions in the .dll loaded by JNI are just wrappers for the Assembly functions.

But I'm not able to resolve the undefined external reference to the Assembly function before the code has been compiled into a .dll that I can link with my .obj file generated by NASM. So, how do I "disable" the linker so there will be no complaints when I build the C++ module?

Comment: you need to build static/dynamic library or whatever it's called there.

Comment: Which C++ compiler are you using, and which version? Are you building that code from an IDE or from the command line?

Comment: the real problem is you can't link your NASM library with C++ code, right?

Comment: Andrey, that's right. I can't link the NASM and C++ code. I'm using Microsoft Visual C++ 2010, and I'm building the C++ code from the IDE.

Comment: Dahse Frederic's answer is correct. In future, pleas ask questions more specifically, because you gave a lot of unneeded details that make question vague.

Answer (score 1):

To link against the `obj` files generated by NASM, open the properties of your C++ project, select `Configuration Properties > Linker > Input`, then add your `obj` files to the `Additional Dependencies` list (delimited by semicolons).

Comment: It claims that my func.obj file is corrupt, how would you generate a .obj file with NASM?

Comment: @Benjamin, the Visual Studio 2010 linker only supports its own variant of the COFF object file format. Apparently, you'll need to pass the `-f win32` option to NASM (instead of `-f coff`) in order to obtain object files in that format.

Comment: Ahh thanks a lot :). But I still get the "unresolved external symbol" error upon linking. This is the output: func.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _sum
1>crash.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "int __cdecl sum(int,int)" (?sum@@YAHHH@Z) referenced in function _Java_Crash_sum@16

Comment: @Benjamin, that looks like a calling convention mismatch. What's the `.model` directive used in your `asm` files? Most of the time, you should go for `__stdcall` instead of `__cdecl` on the C++ side.

Comment: NASM doesn't have a .model directive. This is func.asm: _sum:
    push ebp
    mov  ebp, esp

    mov  eax, [ebp+8]
    mov  ecx, [ebp+12]
    add  eax, ecx
    
    pop  ebp
    ret

Comment: @Benjamin, apologies, I was confusing with MASM. Since your calling convention indeed looks like `__cdecl`, can you put the function declaration inside an `extern "C"` block in your C++ project and check if that fixes your problem?

Comment: Nope. But does the MSVC++ compiler append an underscore before every function name like OSX?

Comment: @Benjamin, [it's supposed to do so](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zkwh89ks.aspx), except when exporting `extern C` functions. Since you're importing `sum()`, not exporting it, it should work. However, try without the underscore, YMMV :)

Comment: Hmm... declaring 'int sum(int, int)' inside an extern C block I still get these linking errors: 1>func.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _sum
1>crash.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _sum

Comment: @Benjamin, okay, the linker seems to be looking for the right symbol. You said the function was called `_sum` in the assembly file, right? It should work. Are you properly exporting the function (using the `global` directive IIRC)?

Comment: Yes. In the top of the Assembly file I have the 'global _sum' directive.

Comment: @Benjamin, then I'm at loss to explain the situation. Can you run [dumpbin /symbols](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/177429) on your `obj` file to double-check the names of the exported symbols?

Comment: Dump of file C:\JVM_Crash\JVM_Crash\func.obj

File Type: COFF OBJECT

COFF SYMBOL TABLE
000 00000000 DEBUG  notype       Filename     | .file
    func.asm
002 00000000 SECT1  notype       Static       | .text
    Section length    D, #relocs    0, #linenums    0, checksum        0
004 00000000 ABS    notype       Static       | .absolut
005 00000000 UNDEF  notype       External     | _add
006 00000001 ABS    notype       Static       | @feat.00

String Table Size = 0x0 bytes

  Summary

           D .text

Comment: @Benjamin, `sum()` doesn't seem to be exported, but `add()` definitely is. Look out for differences between the two functions in your assembly file, that should help you determine what's going wrong.

Comment: Oops, my bad. I forgot to tell you that I renamed _sum to _add because the C++ functions that calls the _sum function is also called sum.

Comment: So now your error is `error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _add`, even if you add the `obj` file to the additional dependencies?

Comment: Yup. This is my Additional Dependencies: C:\JNI\JNI\func.obj;%(AdditionalDependencies)

Comment: I'm jabbing in the dark now, but are you positive that `C:\JVM_Crash\JVM_Crash\func.obj` and `C:\JNI\JNI\func.obj` are the exact same file?

Comment: Positive. It's just me that has been a fool and forget to tell you that I cleaned up project and found that the name was no longer appropiate.

Comment: @Benjamin, then I honestly don't know what's going on. Let's hope someone else thinks of something I haven't.